# OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused - when trying to connect to new postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

I'm changing my development Django Database from sqlite to postgresql.

I've changed my settings to the appropriate values:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        'NAME': "db.postr",
        'USER': "zorgan",
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': "localhost",
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

however when I perform `python manage.py makemigrations` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 110, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 282, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Users/zorgan/Desktop/postr1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I believe the problem is I don't have a Postgres database, however when I perform `sudo -u postgres psql` in my development environment it returns:

```
sudo: unknown user: postgres
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

and this is what I have to do [to create a postgres database](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-the-postgresql-database-and-user).

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a system/postgres config issue and has nothing to do with python nor django.

Comment: restart your postgres server.

Comment: "Any suggestions?" => well yes, read postgresql doc and eventually your os doc for os-specific postgres setup, and make sure you have postgres running and an existing database that you can connect to.

Comment: Restart your Postgresql service and first verify that you can connect to the DB (use any tool like PgAdmin or something similar)

Comment: Thanks guys. I've managed to start the postgres server - however when I try to start a postgres session (so I can create the database) with `sudo -u zorgan postgres psql` - it returns `postgres: invalid argument: "psql"` - if I remove `psql` then it returns `postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.` any idea?